# Stack Overflow (Shellcoder's Handbook)

Tags: security, gdb, stack, overflow, shellcode

I'm currently following the erratas for the [Shellcoder's Handbook (2nd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047008023X). 
The book is a little outdated but pretty good still. My problem right now is that I can't guess how long my payload needs to be I tried to follow every step (and run gdb with the same arguments) and I tried to guess where the buffer starts, but I don't know exactly. I'm kind of new to this too so it makes sense.

I have a vulnerable program with `strcpy()` and a `buffer[512]`. I want to make the stack overflow, so I run some A's with the program (as the Erratas for the Shellcoders Handbook). I want to find how long the payload needs to be (no ASLR) so in theory I just need to find where the buffer is.

Since I'm new I can't post an image, but the preferred output from the book has a full 4 row of 'A's (0x41414141), and mine is like this:

```
(gdb) x/20xw $esp - 532         
0xbffff968 : 0x0000000  0xbfffffa0e 0x41414141 0x41414141
0xbffff968   0x41414141 0x41414141  0x00004141 0x0804834
```

What address is that? How I know where this buffer starts? I want to do this so I can keep working with the book. I realize that the buffer is somewhere in there because of the A's that I ran. But if I want to find how long the payload needs to be I need the point where it starts.

Comment: You could upload the image in imgur and can share here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you copied the output of gdb correctly.  You used the command `x/20xw`, this says you'd like to examine 20 32-bit words of memory, displayed as hex.  As such, each item of data displayed should consist of `0x` followed by 8 characters.  You have some some with only 7, and some with 9.  I'll assume that you copied out the text by hand and made a few mistakes.

The address is the first item displayed on the line, so, for the first line the address is `0xbffff968`, this is the address of the first byte on the line.  From there you can figure out the address of every other byte on the line by counting.

Your second line looks a little messed up, you have the same address, and also you're missing the `:` character, again, I'll assume this is just a result of the copy.  I would expect the address of the second line to be `0xbffff978`.

If the buffer starts with the first word of `0x41414141` then this is at address `0xbffff970`, though an easier way to figure out the address of a variable is just to ask gdb for the address of the variable, so, in your case, once gdb is stopped at a place where `buffer` is in scope:

```
(gdb) p &buffer
$1 = (char (*)[512]) 0xbffff970
```

Answer (score 0):

Metasploit has a nice tool to assist with calculating the offset. It will generate a string that contains unique patterns. Using this pattern (and the value of EIP or whatever other location after using the pattern), you can see how big the buffer should be to write exactly into EIP or whatever other location.

Open the tools folder in the metasploit framework3 folder (I’m using a linux version of metasploit 3). You should find a tool called pattern_create.rb. Create a pattern of 5000 characters and write it into a file:

```
root@bt:/pentest/exploits/framework3/tools# ./pattern_create.rb
Usage: pattern_create.rb length [set a] [set b] [set c]
root@bt:/pentest/exploits/framework3/tools# ./pattern_create.rb 5000
```

Then just replace the A's with the output of the tool. 
Run the application and wait until the application dies again, and take note of the contents of EIP or whatever other location.
Then use a second metasploit tool to calculate the exact length of the buffer before writing into EIP or whatever other location, feed it with the value of EIP or whatever other location(based on the pattern file) and length of the buffer :

```
root@bt:/pentest/exploits/framework3/tools# ./pattern_offset.rb 0x356b4234 5000
1094
root@bt:/pentest/exploits/framework3/tools#
```

1094. That’s the buffer length needed to overwrite EIP or whatever other location.